# Is it possible to test hardware dependent code with Travis CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, devops, travis-ci-cli

I just got to know about Travis CI and went through some of their docs. It seems to be a nice solution for open source projects.

With my reading so far through Travis docs, I am doubtful whether I will be able to connect it to my personal hardware in some manner.

I am working on some IoT related project written in C/C++ hosted on github. Building and publishing images on artifactory, on Travis CI should not be a problem. But when it comes to testing, definitely it cannot be tested on their (Travis's) hardware. The binaries need to be put on my development board (raspberry pi) and then test cases should be executed. Once test suit finishes, Travis CI should be notified of the results.

Is Travis allows such functionality? If not, then it would be a great limitation.

Comment: The best I could find : https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/integration/platformio/

Comment: Link to repo? (If possible)

Comment: Uargh it's really confusing... Wikipedia says it's MIT licensed, so it should be self-hostable, right? Also it says "TravisPro provides custom deployments of a proprietary version on the customer's own hardware." but I couldn't figure out wether it is possible to run only the worker on your hardware. There is [this repository](https://github.com/travis-ci/worker) but it is not really clear how to use it. There are other services which might do the job, e.g. https://buildkite.com/

Answer (score 1):

> But when it comes to testing, definitely it cannot be tested on their
>   (Travis's) hardware

By this statement you answered your own question. If you want to use Travis for showing test status publicly, your best chance is running the tests on premises using Jenkins, GitLab CI or any other CI server and then offering an API to Travis (e.g. a file with the test results). All Travis would then do is fetching and showing the test results.

If you want to control things from within Travis, you could trigger builds from Travis using a HTTP call and then wait for the remote build to finish before showing its results. Both Jenkins and GitLab CI offer remote triggering. However, this requires your CI servers to be publicly accessible, which might be a security risk (e.g. people triggering non-stop builds).

Answer (score 0):

TravisCI is primarily useful for testing libraries and projects that can be run and tested on common systems (linux, etc.) I don't believe there is a way to run TravisCI locally however, MinionCI seems to offer a solution for running a CI server locally following a style similar to TravisCI, check it out [here](https://github.com/timofurrer/minion-ci).